# Loading data into BQ tables - GCP

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I have my source data in BQ and I have to process it and load it into a different BQ table. Currently I am doing it using Dataproc and spark to process and load the data.
Is there any better way of doing the same or any other GCP provided / inbuilt functionality which I can use like DATAFLOW to achieve the same?

Comment: If both the input and output are BQ tables, why don't simply use BQ for that?

Comment: As you described the case, do you think it might be possible to use SQL in BigQuery to process the input data from source tables, and append the result to the target tables? BigQuery might be functionally rich enough to handle what is required. Such solution may be quite reliable, scalable and arguably cheaper than others.

Comment: Why are you using Dataproc? Do you perform external call to enrich your data? What are the key steps that avoid you using raw sql to perform the transformation?

Comment: I need to take data from multiple tables based on the business conditions and calculated the final logic. In many places I am using SQLs but to calculate the final result a lot of business logic is involved so had to do involve spark and scala to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like Dataflow could be a good fit for your case. If you use Python, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/tree/main/Python/bigquery contains a lot of useful code for you to create your own Beam pipelines.